# understand IFNULL mysql

Tags: sql, null, case

I am trying to understand `IFNULL` query when its wrapped in a case statement. I feel like there is redundancy want to understand bit more in detail.

```
SELECT user_id, 
       (CASE WHEN IFNULL(condition,1) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE IFNULL(condition,1) END)::int adjusted_condition, TRANSACT_ID
FROM user_transaction
```

When I am trying to understand the by breaking down
`IFNULL(condition,1)` = This basically assign `1` to condition when condition is `NULL`

Here is the data without the case statement:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+                                           
| USER_ID | CONDITION | TRANSACT_ID |
|---------+-----------+-------------|
|       1 | NULL      |      40779 |
|       4 | NULL      |      40779 |
|       1 | 1         |      40855 |
|       2 | 1         |      40855 |
|       1 | 1         |      40864 |
|       2 | 1         |      40864 |
|       1 | 1         |      40876 |
|       2 | 4         |      40876 |
|       3 | 4         |      40876 |
|       4 | 4         |      40876 |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Why is your question tagged "mysql"?  Your syntax makes sense in Postgres but not MySQL.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense in PostgreSQL either. A condition in PostgreSQL is either true or false or null. Not 1, nor any other number. So `IFNULL(condition,1) = 0` wouldn't make sense. Moreover there is no `IFNULL` in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `condition` is the name of a column in OP's table.

Comment: @forpas: Ah, okay, I took that for pseudo code. (Why would someone call an integer column `condition`? Well, ...) Anyway, this is neither MySQL nor PostgreSQL nor does any other DBMS come to mind where this query would be valid.

Answer (score 2):

First, `ifnull()` is equivalent to `coalesce()`.  I strongly recommend the latter because it is the standard function for replacing `NULL`s.

Second, `ifnull()` is rather redundant in a `case`.  In this case, `NULL`s never match values, so this is equivalent.

Third, I assume you want one of those values to be `0`.  Otherwise the expression always returns `1`:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       (CASE WHEN condition = 0 THEN 1
             ELSE COALESCE(condition, 0)
        END)::int adjusted_condition,
       TRANSACT_ID
FROM user_transaction
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression seems to convert NULL and 0 to 1, otherwise the original value. For clarity, it could simply be written as:

```
CASE WHEN condition IS NULL THEN 1
     WHEN condition = 0 THEN 1
     ELSE condition END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to write the expression, even more concise:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(condition, 0), 1)
```

[NULLIF()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) returns NULL if its two arguments are equal, or else it returns the first argument. So in this expression, it will return NULL if condition is either NULL or 0. So COALESCE() returns 1 if the NULLIF() returns NULL.

If condition is non-NULL but not equal to 0, then NULLIF() will return that non-NULL value, and COALESCE() will also return the same value.

Answer (score 0):

In this case statement:

```
CASE 
  WHEN IFNULL(condition, 1) = 0 THEN 1 
  ELSE IFNULL(condition, 1) 
END
```

if `condition` **is null** then `IFNULL(condition, 1)` returns `1` and (since `1 = 0` returns `false`), 
then `ELSE IFNULL(condition, 1)` returns finally `1`
if `condition` **is 0** then `IFNULL(condition, 1)` returns `0` and (since `0 = 0` returns `true`), 
finally `1` is returned
if `condition` **is not null and is not 0** then `IFNULL(condition, 1)` returns `condition` and (since `condition = 0` returns `false`), 
then `ELSE IFNULL(condition, 1)` returns finally `condition`
 
So it is equivalent to:

```
CASE 
  WHEN IFNULL(condition, 0) = 0 THEN 1 
  ELSE condition 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

A condition (i.e. a boolean expression) is true or false or null. In MySQL these boolean values have numeric equivalents: true = 1, false = 0, null = null. `IFNULL` takes two arguments. If the first argument is null, it returns the second argument, otherwise the first.

Here is what `IFNULL(condition,1)` does:

```
condition           | true = 1 | false = 0 | null
IFNULL(condition,1) | true = 1 | false = 0 | true = 1
```

So an expression that results in null (e.g. `123 = null`)  ends up as true.

Then you apply this case expression:

```
CASE WHEN IFNULL(condition,1) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE IFNULL(condition,1) END
```

In case the `IFNULL` result is 0 (false) the whole case expression becomes 1 (true). Otherwise you keep the `IFNULL` result.

```
condition           | true = 1 | false = 0 | null
IFNULL(condition,1) | true = 1 | false = 0 | true = 1
result              | true = 1 | true = 1  | true = 1
```

You always end up with 1. So you get

```
select user_id, 1 as adjusted_condition, transact_id
from user_transaction
```

Comment: I believe your answer is incorrect when condition has a value of 4; the ELSE clause of the CASE will return condition, so 4